# StackOverFlowException on Merge Sort

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, mergesort

So, I am trying to do merge sorting, but I keep getting a `StackOverFlowException` and I don't quite get what I'm doing wrong. Would this work code work well for merge sorting or would there be a better way to write the code?

```
static public List<string> MergeSort(List<string> list)
        {
            List<string> left = new List<string>();
            List<string> right = new List<string>();

            if (list.Count <= 1)
            {
                return list;
            }

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                if (list.IndexOf(item) <= (list.Count / 2))
                {
                    left.Add(item);
                }
                else
                    right.Add(item);
            }
            left = MergeSort(left);
            right = MergeSort(right);
            return Merge(left, right);
        }
        static public List<string> Merge(List<string> left, List<string> right)
        {
            List<string> merged = new List<string>();

            while (left.Count != 0 && right.Count != 0)
            {
                if (left.First().Length <= right.First().Length)
                {
                    merged.Add(left.First());
                    left.Remove(left.First());
                }
                else
                {
                    merged.Add(right.First());
                    right.Remove(right.First());
                }
            }
            while(left.Count != 0)
            {
                merged.Add(left.First());
                left.Remove(left.First());
            }
            while (right.Count != 0)
            {
                merged.Add(right.First());
                right.Remove(right.First());
            }
            return merged;
        }
```

Comment: Don't use `foreach` and then use `IndexOf` as that will find the index of the first value (which will be incorrect if you have duplicate values).  Just use a `for` loop and you'll have the index as you go.

Comment: Also did you mean to sort on the length of the strings instead of comparing their values?

Comment: i compare there values in the merge here im just spliting them into seprate lists

Comment: `if (left.First().Length <= right.First().Length)` is comparing the length of the string to determine how to sort them.  If you have a list like "abc", "bc", "c" that is already sorted alphabetically this will resort it to "c", "bc", "abc" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with the code that determines which list to put each item into

```
 if (list.IndexOf(item) <= (list.Count / 2))
```

If the list has 2 items then the indexes are 0 and 1 and this condition is true for both so they are both put in the left list and nothing in the right.  Then you call

```
left = MergeSort(left);
```

Which is taking a list with 2 items and again it's going to put both in the left and call this again and put them both in the left and .... forever.

Just change the comparison to

```
 if (list.IndexOf(item) < (list.Count / 2))
```

Additionally you should not use `IndexOf` as it will return the index of the first item instead of the current one if you have duplicates in the list.  So a list with "abc" in it twice will return 0 both times and you'll fall into the same infinite loop.  Instead you can just do a `for` loop like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
     if (i < (list.Count / 2))
     { 
         left.Add(list[i]);
     }
     else 
     {
         right.Add(list[i]);
     }
}
```

Comment: There are other flaws in the code. E.g. it doesn't handle the case of same elements on the list. This is because `list.IndexOf(item)` will always find the very first occurence, regardless of where the item actually is. It would supposedly fall in an infinite loop then, always remaping a list of two elements to the very same list of two elements. Also, the comparising actually compares lengths. I am not sure this is intended. Please edit your answer to reflect these problems as well.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Yeah, I didn't think of the case where using `IndexOf` would cause the same type of infinite loop.  As for comparing the lengths, that's a valid way to sort so I think that merits a comment, but isn't really an answer to the question at hand.

Comment: It's fine now, regards.